# Subnodes in a json template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a template for json using the JB gem:  index.json.jb

https://github.com/amatsuda/jb

It outputs all the settings with some attributes per record.

Settings also have a metadata field, which is a postgres jsonB field.  I'd like to loop through the metadata fields contents and add it to my json template.  I've tried all sorts of ways and I can't figure out how to do this.

```
json = {}

json[:settings] =  @settings.map do |setting|
  {
    id: setting.id,
    category: setting.category,
    created_at: setting.created_at,
    updated_at: setting.updated_at,
    notes: setting.notes,
    name: setting.full_name,
    setting.metadata.map do |meta|
      {
        meta[0]: meta[1]
      }
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: What does `setting.metadata` contain? Is it an array of pairs or something?

Comment: yes.  eg {"color_code"=>"#800080"}  or  {"code"=>"AB  ", "English"=>"Fir"}

Comment: How does it fail? Isn't it failing with `SyntaxError`? The line `setting.metadata.map` has no key like `name:` for the hash. Then I guess it never works…

Comment: Thats an object/hash and don't get why you think you need to iterate though it.

Comment: good point! I get an syntax error: /index.json.jb:15: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => end

Comment: @max - even better point

Comment: If you want to combine two hashes you can just use `.merge(other_hash)`

Comment: For this, I can just do metadata: setting.metadata - because it's a json hash anyway. doh!